# Maven modify dependency jar manifest files

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, manifest, maven-shade-plugin

I'm sorry in advance I can't give the exact code as I don't have it at hand right now. However, I ran into a problem while trying to package my project into a jar. I used maven assembly plugin in my pom.xml to assemble all dependencies and project jar into one place. But now I need all of those dependency jars to have a custom manifest file. Is it possible to inject some properties with Maven itself somehow? Now the only solution I came up with is to use Maven's shade plugin and create an uber-jar, but the problem is that some of dependencies have custom manifests (like Spring framework ones) which gets lost and only one manifest is generated for the uber-jar. Is it possible to somehow tell maven to unpack dependencies, edit manifestEntries and pack them up again and assemble together with the project jar in a zip?

**Long story short:** basically what I want to find out, is would it be possibly to somehow modify a file inside one of the dependencies jar or in all dependency jars at once? Let's say my project has a dependency of spring-beans. Now I would like to modify a specific file inside spring-beans.jar, specifically manifest.md before I assemble them in one zip which should contain project.jar and spring-beans.jar (with a modified manifest.md). I think something similar is achievable with maven antrunner plugin?

**Example:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Project</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                  <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
                  </descriptors>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I want to modify manifest.md in spring-core.jar, spring-context.jar and spring-beans.jar. I know I can use shade plugin to make an uber jar which would have one manifest.md which I could edit within shade's configuration, but if it is possible to somehow modify specific dependency jars alone I think it would be more fool proof and I could use these libraries among several applets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a bit difficult to determine exactly what you're looking for. Can you please rewrite this question in the form of some sort of list indicating the order in which you expect things to happen? Please feel free to refer to the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) entry on writing a good question. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to be more specific this time and added some sample pom.xml text of what it is like now and what I want to achieve :)

Comment: @AlexK sorry to reply so late. No, unfortunately. I had to pack dependencies into uber jars separately for my particular problem.